# Regex for finding ping loss different than 0% on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Im trying to make a simple batch script that will print on file all of the lines that have ping loss different than 0

I start with this and to find all lines that have loss in them
`findstr loss Pingtest.log >>1000.txt`

Output:

> Packets: Sent = 10, Received = 10, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
> Packets: Sent = 10, Received = 10, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
> Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

than i try with
`findstr /r 0% Pingtest.log >>1000.txt`
but it prints out bunch of lines that does not help me.

So how can i make it work when there is line with loss different from 0 to be printed in text file?
Something like:
Output:

> Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (11% loss),

---------Edit
I have file with this information in it

> ўв 25.05.2021 Ј.
> 09:04
>
> Pinging 192.168.0.156 with 32 bytes of data:
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=128
>
> Ping statistics for 192.168.0.156:
> Packets: Sent = 10, Received = 10, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
> Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
> Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 14ms, Average = 9ms
> ўв 25.05.2021 Ј.
> 09:05
>
> Pinging 192.168.0.156 with 32 bytes of data:
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=128
>
> Ping statistics for 192.168.0.156:
> Packets: Sent = 10, Received = 10, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
> Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
> Minimum = 7ms, Maximum = 11ms, Average = 9ms
>
> ўв 25.05.2021 Ј.
> 09:05
>
> Pinging 192.168.0.156 with 32 bytes of data:
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=128
> Reply from 192.168.0.156: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=128
>
> Ping statistics for 192.168.0.156:
> Packets: Sent = 10, Received = 10, Lost = 0 (11% loss), (here i change it from 0 to 11 to test the script)
> Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
> Minimum = 7ms, Maximum = 11ms, Average = 9ms

the result of the

```
@ECHO OFF  
findstr /r /c:"([1-9][0-9]*% loss)" input-file.name >>output-file.name
```

was blank dokument.

Comment: @PhilipScot : You have tagged this question as _bash_, but `findstr` is not a bash command.

Comment: Hi @Jetchisel Im trying to do this on windows, and there is no grep command which i can use

Comment: You seem to confuse bash with batch. Anyway, try with `findstr /R /C:"([1-9][0-9]*% loss)"` (in a batch file, you need to double the `%`-symbol)…

Comment: Hello @aschipfl i try your code but i did not get any results .

Comment: @aschipfl's code works fine for me. At least for an English version of Windows (the output of `ping` is language dependent. To make it "international", filter for `([1-9][0-9]*%` only)

Comment: @Stephan could you share more details how you manage to make it work?
i've tryed but still nothing.

Also i edited my post with more information if you want to check it out

Comment: Note the `ўв` - that's a header for Unicode. `cmd` can't process this properly. You can try `type file.txt|findstr ...`. That *should* work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx to @Stephan
`findstr /RC:"([1-9][0-9]*%% loss)" input.file >>output.file`
is what is worked for me.

> The line works directly on the command line. To use a literal % in a
> batch file, double it (the script parser works slightly different as
> the command line parser): findstr /RC:"([1-9][0-9]*%% loss)"
> input.file >>output.file.